# How to set a tooltip on a JavaFX Button?

Tags: java, css, button, javafx

How can I set a title or a text that appears above a button when I hover it with the mouse?

Comment: Do you want the text to appear on the Button or change the text of the Button?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Tooltip](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tooltip.htm) ?

Answer (score 37):

To add a tooltip in FXML, you could also do this,

```
<Button>
 <tooltip><Tooltip text="my tooltip" /></tooltip>
</Button>
```

Comment: I had to add this: <?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>

For some reason, IntelliJ Idea didn't catch that one automatically.

Comment: @FranMarzoa hmm IntelliJ does that for me, does Ctrl + Alt + O automatically add the import?

Comment: It did it with all other imports, I guess it's a minor glitch.

Comment: Note this only works for things that subclass control - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950542/how-can-i-add-a-tooltip-to-a-node-that-does-not-implement-control-using-fxml

Answer (score 35):

The [`Tooltip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html) class is what you are looking for.

**Example for a simple Tooltip**

```
Button button = new Button("Hover Me");
button.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Tooltip for Button"));
```

[image]

You can also customize your `Tooltip`s: [CSS Reference for Tooltip](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tooltip).

**Example for a styled Tooltip**

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setText("Hover Me!");
Tooltip tt = new Tooltip();
tt.setText("Text on Hover");
tt.setStyle("-fx-font: normal bold 4 Langdon; "
    + "-fx-base: #AE3522; "
    + "-fx-text-fill: orange;");

button.setTooltip(tt);
```

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to point out a tooltip takes 2 seconds of holding the mouse still until it appears. There's most probably a way to customize that time...

Comment: @EgorHans Or maybe a way to show a hint that there is a tooltip for that button, like a small lightbulb

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Scenebuilder, you can add tooltips by locating "Tooltip" under the Miscellaneous dropdown (Left panel) and dragging it to the node you want to install the tooltip. You can then specify various properties (Right panel) of the tooltip like style and text just as you would a normal Node.