# Tooltip not appearing?

Tags: java, javafx

Looking around, it seems that the general consensus for adding a Tooltip is through the Tooltip#install method:

```
Tooltip.install(button, new Tooltip("This is a tooltip"));
```

However, binding this to a button doesn't seem to do anything of the sort.

I'm using JavaFX scene builder and the button I want to have a tooltip added to is configured in my Controller class through @FXML tags.

This is the button in action:

[image]

How does one go about adding a tooltip, then?

Comment: Tooltips usually don't appear until you hold the mouse still for a moment or two: which doesn't seem to ever happen in your animated image. If it's really not working when you hover the mouse (instead of just moving it over the control), post a complete controller example. Aside: note for controls (like buttons) you can also do `button.setTooltip(...)`.

Comment: Is there a way of shortening the time it takes for it to allow it to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from one of a [duplicate question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37543167/1248974):

```
Button btn = new Button("Step");
btn.setTooltip(new Tooltip("This is a tooltip"));
```

[image: This is a tooltip]

As for the time it takes for the Tooltip to appear:

> Typically, the tooltip is "activated" when the mouse moves over a
>   Control. There is usually some delay between when the Tooltip becomes
>   "activated" and when it is actually shown. The details (such as the
>   amount of delay, etc) is left to the Skin implementation.

Taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html